My program works fine but does not return 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i,j;

void display_matrix(int matrix[],int rows,int colombs){
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
     for(j=0;j<colombs;j++)
        printf("%5d ",matrix[i*rows+j]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}

int *create_matrix(int rows,int colombs,int min,int max){
    int *matrix=NULL;
    matrix=(int*)calloc(colombs*rows,sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(j=0;j<colombs;j++)
            matrix[i*rows+j]=(rand()%(max-min+1))+min;
    
    return matrix;
}

int main(){
    
    int *m=NULL,row,col;
    
    do{
        printf("Give the number of rows:\n");
        scanf("%d",&row);
    }while(row<=0);
    
    do{
        printf("Give the number of colombs:\n");
        scanf("%d",&col);
    }while(col<=0);
    
    m=create_matrix(row,col,10,99);
    display_matrix(m,row,col);

    return 0;
}

The matrix is displayed as intended but the program return value is 3221226356. I tried changing the rows and colombs in the function create_matrix() and the return value was 0 but the matrix had trash data.
That is the result after i run the program:


On windows 3221226356 which is 0xc0000374 in hex indicates a heap corruption.

Does it cause any major problems and is there a way to fix this?

i*rows+j is wrong, it should be i*columns+j. You can debug by verifying that the array index at which you write the random numbers to see if it's in-range.

Just as a side note: It is 'column', not 'colomb' ;)

"Does it cause any major problems" ... er... yes.  By overrunning an allocation you are modifying memory the is part of some other object, with unpredictable consequences.  Certainly if you attempt to free the memory allocated for the matrix, it would fail because in this case you have corrupted the heap management structures.  You may also fail to allocate new memory.  What tool chain are you using?  Running in a debugger such as that in Visual Studio (not to be confused with VS Code) will help detect such issues.

Btw, in the future, I'd suggest using a debugger to track down bugs of this and every every other variety. You'd start with a smaller matrix to keep things simple, then step through your code and examine the variables along the way to see if they contain what you expect them to. It's really an essential skill when programming.

@George did you check if my answer solves your problem ? If it does please consider to click the '✔' mark to accept it.

@George Minor issue: Large values: calloc(colombs*rows,sizeof(int)) leads to trouble when colombs*rows is larger than INT_MAX.  Could use calloc(colombs, sizeof(int)*rows) or calloc((size_t)colombs*rows, sizeof(int)) to forestall that overflow unless much larger values are used.  (hmm ,  i*rows+j remains an issue)  Even better, robust code would detect trouble with something like if (colombs > INT_MAX/rows) Handle_Error(); before calloc(colombs*rows,sizeof(int)) and check the return value of calloc().

It seems like you are using Windows.
On Windows error code 3221226356 (which is 0xc0000374 in hex) indicates a heap corruption.
The corruption is caused by writing to your matrix at an invalid index.
Your bug is in converting row and column indices to an index in matrix:
Instead of:   i*rows+j
It should be: i*colombs+j
(since colombs is the stride of the matrix).
You have this bug in 2 places:

When you print the matrix (in display_matrix):
printf("%5d ",matrix[i*rows+j]);

Should be:
printf("%5d ",matrix[i*colombs+j]);


When you fill the matrix (in create_matrix):
matrix[i*rows+j]=(rand()%(max-min+1))+min;

Should be:
matrix[i*colombs+j]=(rand()%(max-min+1))+min;



A side note: colombs should be renamed to columns.

@Rafalon thanks for fixing the typo. As you can see I got it right on the 4th line ;-)

You're welcome! Indeed I saw that - haha. I was about to write a comment about it, but then I realized it would be just as fast to correct it myself
